# ¿Como colocar A1 auto_increment en MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

me han pedido que coloque una tabla y que su ID se autoincremente pero esta tabla tiene que tener un A antes del valor inicial y no se como hacerlo, lo he buscado en foros y demas, pero aun no logro encontrar una solución. Para explicarme mejor. lo que necesito es que la id me muestre: A1, A2, A,3. y asi sucesivamente mientras inserto los datos del autor.

```
create table autor(
    id_autor varchar(10) not null,
    nombre varchar(50) not null,
    apellido varchar(50) not null,
    profesion varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (id_autor)
);
alter table autor auto_increment='A'1;
```

eso fue un intento fallido para que entiendan lo que quiero hacer

Comment: Los valores de una columna con autoincremento deben ser numéricos. Pero si un campo con autoincremento forma parte de un índice compuesto de múltiples columnas, podrías simular lo que necesitas. No se que significa esa `A`, pero podrias generar una nueva columna antes de id_autor, llámala como quieras, como por ejemplo, **grupo**, de este modo: `grupo VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'A'` y luego definir el índice primario de este modo: `PRIMARY KEY (grupo,id)`... de este modo, el dia que cambies esa A por una B entonces la columna con autoincremento empezará con el 1 de nuevo, etc.

Comment: ya hice la prueba y me dio error, talvez no explique bien lo que decía, lo que necesito es que me coloque de la siguiente manera la ID: A1, A2, A3 y así sucesivamente, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Si, te explicastes bien, pero un campo de mysql con autoincremento no soporta los strings, solo campos INT.  Si lo necesitas así deberás forzarlo tu a mano y sin autoincremento, controlándolo de alguna otra forma con algún lenguage de programación que haga las inserciones/modificaciones/eliminaciones de registros que tu quieres, o con triggers.